# Running Multiple Couchbase instances conflict ports?

Tags: couchbase

have a problem when consider about more Couchbase(CB) instances running in same PC. It is because, The screen which allows to add another server provides options to add the second server IP, and no any ports. This might be because each CB communicate through the same port.  How ever without mentioning the connecting port, how to add another server which is running on same PC? (the already running server ip is 127.0.0.1, then what to mention in the second servers IP ?)![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for running this would be to use virtual machines to run the CB instances. Use 1 VM per node/instance (which can be quickly provisioned using [vagrant](http://github.com/couchbaselabs/vagrants)). This (particularly the vagrant solution) allows multiple nodes/instances to communicate between each other on correct ports (as each node is given a unique IP (from the reserved private addresses), and is well tested in terms of resource usage/performance.

More information along with prebuilt vagrant configurations can be found on [GitHub](http://github.com/couchbaselabs/vagrants) and at [this blog](http://nitschinger.at/A-Couchbase-Cluster-in-Minutes-with-Vagrant-and-Puppet) (one of Couchbase's engineers).